# Why can't i access my public IP-Adress from outside my LAN?

Tags: networking, internet, port-forwarding, raspberry-pi

I'm setting up a webserver on my Raspberry PI and I want to make the webserver available on the internet.

I have Portforwarded incoming requests on mypublicip:80 to be forwarded to myraspberrypiip:80 and that should be it right? but it does not work.

In the configuration file of the apache server it says that it is listening to port 80. I have tried to turn off the firewall on my router but nothing changes. I have tried to access the webserver trough SSH (with PuTTY) and added a portforwarding rule that it should forward requests on mypublicip:22 to myraspberrypiip:22 (when i sat in my local publiclibrary and studied and used its wifi) nothing happend i probably did that wrong or something. My IP address for the raspberry pi is static. I can however access the website when im connected to the same wifi and entering its ipv4 adress in the webbrowser.

I saw this [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/681186) on another post of a similar problem at Server Fault.

I think he is on to something here that is relevant to me but do you guys have any suggestions?

Comment: Check that your ISP is actually assigning you a static public IP. Most ISPs do their own NAT now, where multiple users will share the same public IP, but may assign you one if you ask (or pay). In this case, traffic to that IP would never reach your router.

Comment: I'm able to connect to the routers GUI through port 8080 with the routers public IPv4.  Doesn't that mean that the public IP address works?

Comment: Yep, you should be fine there. Does your router have a packet capture utility you could use to test that it's receiving the traffic on port 22/80 that it should be? You could do the same on the Pi.

Comment: Is the "public IPv4" router address you mention in the `10.x.x.x`, `192.168.x.x` or `172.16.x.x` ranges?

Comment: @Simon: Yes that means the address works, but **doesn't mean it's actually a public address.** (As long as you're doing this from the inside, the connection remains fully inside – it doesn't go out to the internet and back – so you'd get the same results with any kind of address the router happens to have.) If the router's "WAN" address is in the 100.64.0.0/10 range it is not public.

Comment: The "public" IPv4 adress according to my router is 83.x.x.x  Does that mean it is not public? Is it possible to solve this kind of problems yourself without paying my ISP? I wanna clearify that i can use my cellular data which has a diffrent ISP to connect to the routers' GUI through port 8080. That means that the request sent from my phone goes through cellular towers and hops to a WAN and the to my router right? which means it is possible to access the router through WAN but not through port 80.Earlier i've asked my ISP if they block any ports and they dont.

Comment: netmask 255.255.248.0

Comment: Yes, it's a public address, and if you're able to connect from outside to the router itself then the rest is your router's job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solved**

I turned on DMZ on my WiFi's GUI and added my Raspberry pi´s Local ip adress and the webserver is now accessible on the internet.
Thanks for all the answers!!!!!

Comment: Excellent, if this was your solution feel free to mark your own answer as the accepted answer.

Comment: love this website. Done.

Comment: @Simon do you also need to put the port with your public IP to access your server?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that you are behind carrier-grade NAT ([CGNAT](https://www.a10networks.com/blog/what-is-carrier-grade-nat-cgn-cgnat/)). As one user said, the public IP address your router reports is not a public address in the common sense of the term at all. Traffic from outside your ISP's network will not reach the address.

The address "appears" to work because you are attempting to access it from inside the ISP's network. That is why accessing from the local library doesn't work.

I suggest using the tool [CanYouSeeMe](https://www.a10networks.com/blog/what-is-carrier-grade-nat-cgn-cgnat/) and probing the ports. I suspect you will get a time-out error. If that is the case, you are indeed behind CGNAT.

You cannot do anything to resolve this issue yourself. You must contact your ISP and inquire whether they can remediate the situation. Often, extra monthly payment is necessary.

Comment: I dont access it through the ISP´s network i think. I can use my cellular data which has a diffrent ISP to access my routers GUI through its "public" IPv4 and with port 8080. I couldn't access the router through port 22 at the library.

Comment: the access through port 8080 was a setting i could turn on, within the routers GUI btw.

Comment: @Joseph I'm also facing same problem. But if OP's problem was indeed CGNAT, I wonder how he managed to solve it?